# amsmath bullet has everything in italics following bullet

Tags: math-mode

LaTeX noob question:

I would like to type `a bullet b = 55`.

For this I am doing `a\bullet{b} = 55`.

However, everything after bullet is in italics. Not sure if I wrote the correct syntax.

Comment: You can use `a \textbullet{} b`. However, since it seems like you're setting up an equation, it's best to use `$a \mathbin{\bullet} b = 55$`, where `\mathbin` sets the appropriate "binary relation" spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose `\bullet` in `$$`(math mode):

```
a$\bullet$b = 55
```